# Django: Returning models.CharField() value from getter method is empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Here is my model class. In this I've added a new getter method `url()` to return a url string for an author profile. But when I'm calling this method in html template file this shows empty.

See here is my usage example:

**Author Model Class:**

```
from django.db import models
import re

class Author(models.Model):
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.EmailField()
    headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='author_headshots')

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def url(self):
        return re.sub(r"[\s|\.|\-|\_|\'|\+]+", "-", self.name)
```

**Passed `Author` object context to template from view method:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from author.models import Author

def index(request):
    authors = Author.objects.order_by('-name')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
                                         'authors': authors
                                         })
```

**And in template(home.html) using as below:**

```
{% if authors %}
    {% for author in authors %}
    <h2><a href="author/{{ author.url }}/">{{ author.name }}</a></h2>
    <p>About author {{ author.name }} here</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
No Authors
{% endif %}
```

**Getting output:**

```
<h2><a href="author//">XXX</a></h2>
<p>About author XXX here</p>
...
```

**Expecting:**

```
<h2><a href="author/xxx/">XXX</a></h2>
<p>About author XXX here</p>
...
```

Comment: Have you check that your `re.sub` call indeed returns the expected string?

Comment: Apart from the empty string problem: Have you looked into [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url), [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse), and [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify)?

Comment: It is not problem with re.sub. Shows empty even I return `self.name` only instead `re.sub(r"[\s|\.|\-|\_|\'|\+]+", "-", self.name)`

Comment: @alko Yes I've passed author object to template

Comment: Please show the view code.

Comment: Sure @DanielRoseman, Added view code above to question

Comment: Weird stuff. When I was testing your code, Author.url returned `<property object at 0x10d3aaba8>` and Author.name returned a regular string. Maybe it has something to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something. Instead of defining a property of a model define a global function like this one (in your views file):

```
def url(Author):
    try:
        Author.url=re.sub(r"[\s|\.|\-|\_|\'|\+]+", "-", Author.name)
    except:
        Author.url='Error!'
```

and then in your index view add this:

```
for author in authors:
    url(author)
    #print author.url
```

Comment: Not actually. Because return string from `url()` method will be different for different model types. Like for Post `url()` will return something like: "/news/2013/11/06/news-post-title-as-slug/440/"

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA Sorry, I thought you needed a solution only for your Author model. If you need something else, then please edit your question...